# Notifying WPF DataGrid on changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to the `ICollectionView` (with filter on). More specifically, I have set `view.Filter = SomeFilteringFunction` which uses `public DateTime DateFrom { get... set... }` property, also bound to the `DatePicker`.

Well, and now, when I change `DatePicker`, bound property `DateFrom` is correctly changed but the DataGrid is not obviously re-filtered.

What is the most right way how to notify `DataGrid` to update itself?

Thank you in advance!

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be binding directly to the ICollectionView, rather you bind to the source collection, and then apply the filter to the ICollectionView returned by CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView.

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

```cs
// should raise INotityPropertyChange.PropertyChanged
public ObservableCollection<Entity> MyCollection { get; set; }

MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Entity>(ctx.EntitySet)); 
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);
view.Filter = SomeFilteringFunction;
```

Then when the value of the DatePicker changes you need to tell the ICollectionView to update.

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);
view.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't understand to what should I bind. I bind to: `list = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new ObservableCollection<Entity>(ctx.EntitySet));`

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event (which i assume you implemented on the class) and refresh the view in the handler:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Collection);
if (view != null)
{
    view.Refresh();
}
```

Not sure if there is a cleaner way, though, but i'm quite positive you need to make that `Refresh` call at one point.